# is there some basic text editor like Notepad++ for Ubuntu that supports emmet/zen coding?

Tags: 20.04, geany, notepad-plus-plus

I would like to use emmet/zen coding on Ubuntu but I haven't found any simple text editor that supports it preferably with easy to install way. A plugin for Geany (which is pretty similar to Notepad++) is very old and hard to install. Are there some other editors?

UPD: I've found Bluefish that is even more alike Notepad++, shortcuts and functionality are pretty close in default package.

Notepad++ as snap is slow (main reason) and ugly and also Emmet is not in the main plugin repository. It is hard to install emmet for notepad++ as well.

Comment: Did you try `apt search emmet` snap `snap search emmet`?

Comment: [Geany snippets](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#user-definable-snippets) could be an alternative, did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Most popular that I know, is Sublime text:
https://www.sublimetext.com/download

To install:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -+
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: Yeah, Sublime is fine but I would like to not close update alert every time I want to edit a plain text file

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Notepadqq](https://snapcraft.io/notepadqq) as alternative using commands below

```
snap install --classic notepadqq
```

Comment: it is abandoned, no updates for two years